# Call to a member function store() on null laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.3

Hi I am trying to upload images and i keep getting an error **"Call to member function store()" on null.**

I have added use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile; 
at the top of the file i thought it could be the issue.

please assist thanks.

Controller

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $file = request()->file('avator')->store('events');

    Events::Create($request->all() + ['image' => $file]);

    return redirect('events');
}
```

view

```
  <div class="header">
                            <h4 class="title">New Event</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                           {!! Form::open(['url' => '/newevent']) !!}

                    <div class="row">   
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                         <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('heading', 'Heading') !!}

                        {!! Form::text('heading', null, ['class' => 'form-control border-input', 'placeholder' => 'Heading']) !!}
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                     {!! Form::label('body', 'Body')!!}

                    {!! Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control border-input', 'placeholder' => 'Body to Events']) !!}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                       </div>

                        <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                     {!! Form::label('avator', 'Image')!!}

                    {!! Form::file('avator', ['class' => 'form-control border-input']) !!}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                       </div>


                                <div class="text-center">
                      {!! Form::submit('Save Me!', ['class'=> 'btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd']) !!}

                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            {!! Form::close() !!} 
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget to add `'files'=> true` in your `array()` of `Form::open()` function, you can do it as:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/newevent', 'files' => true)) }}
```

otherwise you can use the html form tag as:

```
<form action="/newevent" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

[Docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#file-input)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if there is file first:

```
if (request()->hasFile('avator')) {
    $file = request()->file('avator')->store('events');
    Events::Create($request->all() + ['image' => $file]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for @ Alexey Mezenin and @iCode. You both assisted to solve it.